# How to change the Google Fonts link into css @import to fetch the fonts locally

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a working code which I found here [Google Font selector by **elemon**](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/ENpWt/)

and it's working perfectly but as I am building an off-line app I will need to load the fonts from a folder instead. But I have messed up on the try.
The code is as follows:

```js
var FragBuilder = (function() {
    var applyStyles = function(element, style_object) {
        for (var prop in style_object) {
            element.style[prop] = style_object[prop];
        }
    };
    var generateFragmentFromJSON = function(json) {
        var tree = document.createDocumentFragment();
        json.forEach(function(obj) {
            if (!('tagName' in obj) && 'textContent' in obj) {
                tree.appendChild(document.createTextNode(obj['textContent']));
            } else if ('tagName' in obj) {
                var el = document.createElement(obj.tagName);
                delete obj.tagName;
                for (part in obj) {
                    var val = obj[part];
                    switch (part) {
                    case ('textContent'):
                        el.appendChild(document.createTextNode(val));
                        break;
                    case ('style'):
                        applyStyles(el, val);
                        break;
                    case ('childNodes'):
                        el.appendChild(generateFragmentFromJSON(val));
                        break;
                    default:
                        if (part in el) {
                            el[part] = val;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
                tree.appendChild(el);
            } else {
                throw "Error: Malformed JSON Fragment";
            }
        });
        return tree;
    };
    var generateFragmentFromString = function(HTMLstring) {
        var div = document.createElement("div"),
            tree = document.createDocumentFragment();
        div.innerHTML = HTMLstring;
        while (div.hasChildNodes()) {
            tree.appendChild(div.firstChild);
        }
        return tree;
    };
    return function(fragment) {
        if (typeof fragment === 'string') {
            return generateFragmentFromString(fragment);
        } else {
            return generateFragmentFromJSON(fragment);
        }
    };
}());

function jsonp(url) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = url;
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(script);
}

function replacestyle(url) {
    if (!document.getElementById('style_tag')) {
        var style_tag = document.createElement('link');
        style_tag.rel = 'stylesheet';
        style_tag.id = 'style_tag';
        style_tag.type = 'text/css';
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style_tag);
        replacestyle(url);
    }
    document.getElementById('style_tag').href = url;
}

function loadFonts(json) {
    var select_frag = [
        {
        'tagName': 'select',
        'id': 'font-selection',
        'childNodes': [
            {
            'tagName': 'option',
            'value': 'default',
            'textContent': 'Default'}
        ]}
    ];
    json['items'].forEach(function(item) {
        var family_name = item.family,
            value = family_name.replace(/ /g, '+');

        if (item.variants.length > 0) {
            item.variants.forEach(function(variant) {
                value += ':' + variant;
            });
        }

        select_frag[0].childNodes.push({
            'tagName': 'option',
            'value': value,
            'textContent': family_name
        });
    });

    document.getElementById('container').appendChild(FragBuilder(select_frag));
    document.getElementById('font-selection').onchange = function(e) {
        var font = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,
            name = this.options[this.selectedIndex].textContent;
        if (font === 'default') {
            document.getElementById('sink').style.fontFamily = 'inherit';
        } else {
            document.getElementById('sink').style.fontFamily = name;
            replacestyle('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=' + font);
        }
    };
}

jsonp("https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?key=AIzaSyDBzzPRqWl2eU_pBMDr_8mo1TbJgDkgst4&sort=trending&callback=loadFonts");
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
<div id="sink">
<h1>HTML Ipsum Presents</h1>
           
<p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em> Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>

<h2>Header Level 2</h2>
           
<ol>
   <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
   <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
</ol>

<blockquote><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna. Cras in mi at felis aliquet congue. Ut a est eget ligula molestie gravida. Curabitur massa. Donec eleifend, libero at sagittis mollis, tellus est malesuada tellus, at luctus turpis elit sit amet quam. Vivamus pretium ornare est.</p></blockquote>

<h3>Header Level 3</h3>

<ul>
   <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
   <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
</ul>

<pre><code>
#header h1 a { 
    display: block; 
    width: 300px; 
    height: 80px; 
}
</code></pre>
</div>
```

What I need is help in changing, in the above code, the source of the font files from Google fonts to point to a self hosted font folder and if possible I would like to store the id or name of the choosen font in localStorage in a way that the above code would be able to to load it across sessions.

Comment: I just have edited the answer to make more clear and accesible the requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>Update 2021/7/27 20:00</sub>

Code you're trying to modify is very **overcomplicated**. If you have a self-hosted font folder just **import** the font using [`@font-face`](//dev.mozilla.org/docs/CSS/@font-face) and create a simple HTML [`select`](//dev.mozilla.org/docs/HTML/Element/select)ion.

```js
selection = document.querySelector('select#font')
selection.addEventListener('change', style)

function style()
{ document.body.style.fontFamily = selection.value }
```

```html
<select name="font" id="font">
    <option value="Arial">Arial</option>
    <option value="Calibri">Calibri</option>
    <option value="Consolas">Consolas</option>
    <option value="Segoe UI">Segoe UI</option>
</select>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Pellentesque elit ullamcorper dignissim cras tincidunt. Interdum consectetur libero id faucibus. Libero nunc consequat interdum varius sit amet mattis vulputate.</p>
```

[<kbd>Interactive Code</kbd>](//jsitor.com/lxQsUlxxc)

<sub><s>You don't even need to save any value as it is attached to the [`body`](//dev.mozilla.org/docs/HTML/Element/body)</s></sub>

You will need to save **one** value. The chosen font can be simply saved to the [`localStorage`](//dev.mozilla.org/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

```
localStorage.font = selection
```

and loaded.

```
document.querySelector(`option[value=${localStorage.getItem(font)}]`).click()
```

<sup>More information at [Using the Web Storage API](//dev.mozilla.org/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API)</sup>.

Comment: Luko Foks, thanks for the answer but the idea is not to store the font itself in the localStorage but just and id or name related to the selected font which allows to serve it from a self hosted font folder. The cache strategy is not a good idea because the app should require at some stages to clen it and it would force the user to reselect the font of his/her choice.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I updated the answer so it fits your need.

Comment: Luko Foks, how this code is getting a specific font from the fonts folder? Still I need to store an id to call it later on reload. Please, provide a more complete code so I can understand how it works. As in my complicated code the only thing I know to be changed is this two lines: `replacestyle('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=' + font);` and `jsonp("https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?key=AIzaSyDBzzPRqWl2eU_pBMDr_8mo1TbJgDkgst4&sort=trending&callback=loadFonts");` so they point to font folder istead of Google Fonts as it is doing right now. But I've messed up on the try.

Comment: If you don't wish to cache `fonts.googleapis.com` forget about the code. It is not about changing the two lines. You would have to write the fonts in format of the [JSON](https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?key=AIzaSyDBzzPRqWl2eU_pBMDr_8mo1TbJgDkgst4&sort=trending&callback=loadFonts "Google APIs"). Remember, the code is made for Google Fonts. And it's also unnecessarily long. I recommend creating your own code based on the one I've provided.

Comment: *Still I need to store an id to call it later on reload.* That's **true**. I updated my question implementing this feature. *How is this code getting a specific font from the fonts folder?* Simply import the font with [@font-face](https://dev.mozilla.org/docs/CSS/@font-face "MDN Web Docs") and that's all!

Comment: You know, I am very knew to javascript and there are many many things I don't know how to do. This one, _Simply import the font with @font-face_, I know how to do that, with css, but it will import just the font I specify there. I think I can specify more than one, but, how I make the js to pick just the user selected one? That's the question in which I'm stuck. I've tried many aproaches but none working. Now, related to the code I have provided I know is quite complicated and also that it probably has many stuff which I just can get rid off but I just simply don't know how to do.

Comment: **No problem**. You have nothing to fear of! Just ask and we will help you. I see what you are struggling with... and it is simpler than you think! Look at this [example](https://dev.mozilla.org/docs/CSS/@font-face#examples "MDN Web Docs"). `@font-face` will **define** the font *(give it a name, source and weight)* and then they style the `body` with the font. Done. It's easy as that! This is how you use a font. In the code above we use JavaScript instead of CSS to style the body. But it is very similar isn't it? `document.body.style.fontFamily = 'Arial'`

Comment: The implementation of changing fonts is already in my code. It uses default Windows 10 fonts. So if you are running this Operating system, you can already see changes. It is up to you to include your fonts and change the [`option`](https://dev.mozilla.org/docs/HTML/Element/option "MDN Web Docs") [`value`](https://dev.mozilla.org/docs/HTML/Element/option#attr-value "MDN Web Docs") to the font name. `<option value="Arial"></option>`

Comment: I have already found a simple solution using the example you provided on the edition of your answer, [link](https://dev.mozilla.org/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API) and you was perfectly right, it was simpler than I have thought, just added a `@font-face` for each font in the css and refactored the js to my needs. Now it's working fine. I have accepted and voted your answer but anyway will add another myself in case someone else is having the same problem. Thank you very much for your help and pattience.

Answer (score 0):

For future people in trouble:

```
    <!-- HTML -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
<p>This example is designed to demonstrate usage of the     <a href="http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/">W3C Web Storage API   </a>. It should work as far back as IE8. Choose custom background colours, logos and fonts from the below drop down menus, then try closing and reopening the page — you will find that your choices are remembered, as they are stored using Web Storage. You can also visit the   <a href="event.html" target="_blank">storage event output   </a> (opens in new tab). Open this, change some values in the index page, then look at the events page — you'll see the storage changes reported.   </p>

<form>

<label for="font">Choose font style:    </label>
<select id="font">
<option value="'Mint Spirit', sans-serif" selected>Mint Spirit  </option>
<option value="'Bebas Neue', sans-serif">Bebas Neue </option>
</select>


</form>

</body>
</html>
```

```
    @font-face { font-family: 'Mint Spirit'; src: url('../fonts/mintspirit-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/mintspirit-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/mintspirit-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/mintspirit-regular.svg#mint_spiritregular') format('svg'); font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; } @font-face { font-family: 'Mint Spirit'; src: url('../fonts/mintspirit-bold.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/mintspirit-bold.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/mintspirit-bold.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/mintspirit-bold.svg#mint_spiritbold') format('svg'); font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; } @font-face { font-family: 'Mint Spirit'; src: url('../fonts/mintspirit-italic.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/mintspirit-italic.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/mintspirit-italic.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/mintspirit-italic.svg#mint_spirititalic') format('svg'); font-weight: normal; font-style: italic; } @font-face { font-family: 'Mint Spirit'; src: url('../fonts/mintspirit-bolditalic.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/mintspirit-bolditalic.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/mintspirit-bolditalic.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/mintspirit-bolditalic.svg#mint_spiritbold_italic') format('svg'); font-weight: bold; font-style: italic; }
@font-face { font-family: 'Bebas Neue'; src: url('../fonts/BebasNeue-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/BebasNeue-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/BebasNeue-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/BebasNeue-regular.eot') format('truetype'); font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; }


html,body {
margin: 0;
}

html {
font-size: 1rem;
font-family: sans-serif;

}

/* Typography */

h1 {
font-size: 6rem;
}

body,p,form,li {
font-size: 1.6rem;
line-height: 1.5;
font-family: 'Bebas Neue', sans-serif;
}
```

```
var fontElem = document.querySelector('body');
var fontForm = document.getElementById('font');

if(!localStorage.getItem('font')) {
populateStorage();
} else {
setStyles();
}

function populateStorage() {
localStorage.setItem('font', document.getElementById('font').value);
setStyles();
}

function setStyles() {
var currentFont = localStorage.getItem('font');
document.getElementById('font').value = currentFont;
fontElem.style.fontFamily = currentFont;
}
fontForm.onchange = populateStorage;
```